# How to make div push down another div in dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a dropdown menu (vertical) using divs, but I can't get the dropdown contents to push down the other menu (it's overflowing).

I noticed that when I put the code into JSFiddle, it doesn't show the dropdown at all, so I hope this picture help.

[Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWrdh.jpg)

```js
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar_menu .dropbtn").click(function() {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#menu_container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  background-image: url("D:/Website/Website/MyBB_Website/Test/images/black_filter.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar_menu {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Style The Dropdown Button */

#sidebar_menu .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2383AF;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 250px;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #185E7C;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

#sidebar_menuv .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

#sidebar_menu .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2383AF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu_container">
  <div id="sidebar_menu">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">LOGIN</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Website Login Box Display Here</a>
      </div>
      <button class="dropbtn">REGISTER</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Register Here</a>
      </div>
      <button class="dropbtn">LOST PASSWORD?</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Get Password Here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#sidebar_menu .dropdown-content
```

should have position: static instead of absolute.

Comment: Great answer, I will add that browsers default position is static, so just remove the line.